# as3 alpha property with slider not working as expected

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am using a slider to adjust alpha property (opacity) of an image. however it is not working as expected. when alpha is set to 1 (i.e maximum on the slider) then the image shows, but as soon as i slide to any value less than one then the image dissapears completely. i.e at all vales btw 0 and 0.99 there is no image...i a guessing that it is setting alpha at 0 for for all values less than 1. i am a newbie with as3. this is what i have

package {

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;


public class PicturePanel extends MovieClip {
sliderA.width=125;
        sliderA.x=425;
        sliderA.y=15;
        addChild(sliderA);
        sliderA.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, FnNewA);
        sliderA.minimum=0;
        sliderA.maximum=100;
        sliderA.value=100;
        pctPicture.txtA.text= "alpha = " + (sliderA.value/100);



function FnNewA(event:SliderEvent):void {

   pctPicture.txtA.text=""+event.value/100;
        chief.gameBoard.gameNewPctA=event.value/100;
        chief.gameBoard.FnEditPicture();

    }


public function FnPanelSliderStart():void {

sliderA.value=chief.gameBoard.gameNewPctA*100;
        pctPicture.txtA.text=""+sliderA.value;

}
 }

package 
{

import flash.display.*;
import flash.geom.*;
import flash.events.*;
import fl.motion.MatrixTransformer;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

import flash.filters.ConvolutionFilter;

import flash.text.*;

import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;


public class GameBoard extends MovieClip
{
private var newPctA:Number = 1;


public function FnEditPicture():void
    {
         arraySprite[chief.gamePanel.numSprite].getChildAt(0).alpha = gameNewPctA; 

}


private function FnPanelPictureStartOne():void
    {
                    newPctA = 1;            
        pctPanel.FnPanelSliderStart();
    }

private function FnPanelPictureStartTwo():void
    {

newPctA =arraySprite[chief.gamePanel.numSprite].getChildAt(0).alpha;


        pctPanel.FnPanelSliderStart();
    }



public function set gameNewPctA(value:int):void
    {
        newPctA = value;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------
    public function get gameNewPctA():int
    {
        return newPctA;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run in debug mode, are you getting any errors when you do?  It's always difficult to understand Flash problems since things can be organized within the project in many different ways.  For example is this your Main class code, if so where is the class definition and the package definition?

Comment: debug shows no errors. i have added definitions to above code. this is part of a  larger project and the code is fragmented in a few files. i have isolated just the alpha slider code.

Comment: It's too difficult to tell what's going on with the code being un-organized in the post.  Try to edit to correct it, you can type the file name above where the code is like [PicturePanel.as] hit enter a couple of times, copy and paste your code directly from the file then highlight all the code you pasted and press the {} code button above the editor here on SO.  You're value when you trace it should end up between 0 and 1 as you say, is it always tracing only 0 or 1? trace it in FnEditPicture

Comment: The posted code will not compile. the class named PicturePanel doesn't even have a package let alone the class level members are not even type cast. Are you sure you are telling us everything Russ

Comment: ran the trace and it is always tracing 0.

Comment: Well there's you're problem, but without having the code fixed above so we can see what's really going on you won't get a clear answer, there are too many problems with how it's currently posted to make sense out of what's going wrong vs what was just pasted wrong.  As @The_asMan says as is this wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your getter and setter functions returning/taking Integers instead of Numbers. Int will always round down to the nearest whole number (0 in this case). Use Number instead to get the decimal value.

```
public function set gameNewPctA(value:Number):void
    {
        newPctA = value;
    }
//--------------------------------------------------
public function get gameNewPctA():Number
    {
       return newPctA;
    }
}
```